# How to get the missing entries between two CSV files in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV1 file as

```
Identity, AdName,Location,State
345,Demo,San Francisco,CA
587,Cusco,Freemont,CA
899,Rest,Werchesye,CA
```

And another CSV2 file as

```
Identity,AdName,Location,State,LocationCode
345,Demo,San Francisco,CA,90
587,Cusco,Freemont,CA,89
```

I want the desired output

```
Identity, AdName,Location,State
899,Rest,Werchesye,CA
```

Basically i want the missing information in CSV file 2 from that of 1? 
How to do it in R? New to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two files can be joined by the `Identity` column, here you:

```
f1 <- read.csv('file1.csv')
f2 <- read.csv('file2.csv')
diff <- subset(f1, !Identity %in% f2$Identity)
write.csv(diff, file='diff.csv', quote=F, row.names=F)
```

The `subset` takes the rows from `f1` (your first dataset) where the `Identify` field does not exist in `f2$Identity` (your second dataset).

When writing the result to csv, I set some non-default values `quote=F, row.names=F` to match the format you asked for.